# Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/$%7Bthis.apiUrl%7D/server/list: 404 Not Found"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get a back a list of servers I have in mysql database but I keep getting the 404 not found error even though the API works just fine in the backend.

Here's my server.service.ts :

```
  
  servers$ = <Observable<CustomResponse>>
    this.http.get<CustomResponse>('${this.apiUrl}/server/list')
    .pipe (
      tap(console.log),
      catchError(this.handleError)

    );
```

and here's my app.copmonent.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  appState$: Observable<AppState<CustomResponse>>;
  constructor(private serverService: ServerService){

  }
  ngOnInit() : void{
    this.appState$ = this.serverService.servers$
      .pipe(
        map( response => {
          return { dataState: DataState.LOADED_STATE, appData: response}
          }),
        startWith({dataState: DataState.LOADING_STATE}),
        catchError(( error: string) => {
          console.log(this.appState$);
          return of({ dataState: DataState.ERROR_STATE, error});
  })
      );
  }

}
```

here's what I get when I navigate to http://localhost:4200 :

*{ "dataState": "ERROR_STATE ", "error": "An error occurred - Error code: ${error.status}" }*

here's the error when I inspect :

*GET http://localhost:4200/$%7Bthis.apiUrl%7D/server/list 404 (Not Found)*

Answer (score 3):

```js
  servers$ = <Observable<CustomResponse>>
    this.http.get<CustomResponse>(`${this.apiUrl}/server/list`)
    .pipe (
      tap(console.log),
      catchError(this.handleError)

    );
```

Use backticks, not quotes.